# Listening to the scroll direction only ONCE on devices with continuous scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, logic, settimeout, mousewheel

We're trying to make a pseudo scrolling effect on the homepage of our website but we're running into an issue with the scrolling mechanics touchpads and other digital scrolling mice have (which have a continuing scrolling effect with an easing out timing function).

We want to be able to listen to the direction of the scroll (currently using .on('scroll mousewheel') ) to determine the direction of the scroll (therefore deciding if we should show the previous or next slide) but not listen to every scroll event as this would lead to a series of flashing, seizure-inducing flurry of changes (these being hidden/shown using javascript depending on the scroll value).

We currently have a setTimeout() function that waits 50ms per scroll event before executing the code that actually makes the changes, but this can lead to a longer wait than expected on the aforementioned devices due to their ability to continuously scroll on a swipe, thus continuously refreshing the 50ms wait. This also doesn't take into consideration the easing out scrolling that digital scroll wheels have that allow it to still fire more than once towards the end of the scroll.

So, in essence, we seem to be looking for one of the following:

1. Listening to the direction of the mousewheel direction without
   firing the function every instance of that scroll.
2. Another workaround we haven't thought about yet.

Here's the current section of javascript related to this:

```
var timer;
$('html').on ('scroll mousewheel', function (e) {
  if(timer) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  }

  timer = window.setTimeout(function() {

  var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;

    if((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset ) >= document.body.offsetHeight && delta < 0){

      $(allSections[scrollNumber]).hide();
      $(".cc-nav-circle").removeClass("active");
      if(scrollNumber >= allSections.length - 1){
        scrollNumber = 0; 
      } else {
        scrollNumber++;
      }  

    } else if($(window).scrollTop() === 0 && delta > 0){

      $(allSections[scrollNumber]).hide();
      $(".cc-nav-circle").removeClass("active");
      if(scrollNumber <= 0){
        scrollNumber = allSections.length - 1; 
      } else {
        scrollNumber--;
      }

    }

    $(allSections[scrollNumber]).show();
    $(allCircles[scrollNumber]).addClass("active");

  }, 50);  

});
```

Here's the current in-progess version of this website: https://unink-marketing.squarespace.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of delaying your scroll function until the user is done scrolling, you can scroll right away and just ignore further scroll events until the 50ms timer completes. See the updated code below

```
var timer;
var justScrolled = false;
$('html').on ('scroll mousewheel', function (e) {
  if(timer) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  }

  timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
    justScrolled = false;
  }, 50); 

  if(justScrolled) {
    return;
  }

  justScrolled = true;
  // Do scroll stuff 

});
```

Comment: We ended up doing something else instead (had a physical scroll distance to use instead), but this sounds like it would've worked! I'm considering this question answered! Thanks a lot!